# passing data from recyclerView to another recycleView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

i m trying to pass data from recyclerView that is connected to database with another recyclerView in another activity as search and shopping cart to be able to add it back to data base as an order, i m not sure if i did everything right as the resources online of this subject is very limited. i m not getting any error also i m not getting the data.

> I know the problem but i dont know how to solve it.
>
> how to Cast Textview in the recyclerView layout. i treid inflater but it says cannot reslove method

---

**RecyclerView Adapter for data coming from database**

---

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private static final String TAG = "RecyclerAdapter";

private List<ModelClass> modelClassList;

private Context mContext;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<ModelClass> modelClassList) {
    this.modelClassList = modelClassList;
    mContext = context;


}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v); //ini
    // sialisasi ViewHolder




    return holder;


}

@NonNull
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

    final ModelClass data =modelClassList.get(i);

    myViewHolder.mactivity.setText(data.getActivity());
    myViewHolder.morigin.setText(data.getOrigin());
    myViewHolder.mdestination.setText(data.getDestination());
    myViewHolder.mdescription.setText(data.getDescription());
    myViewHolder.mdate_from.setText(data.getDate_from());
    myViewHolder.mdate_to.setText(data.getDate_to());
    myViewHolder.mprice.setText(data.getPrice());

    myViewHolder.btnadd.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Clicked on"+ data.getActivity());

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,CART.class);
            intent.putExtra("activity", data.getActivity());
            intent.putExtra("origin",data.getOrigin());
            intent.putExtra("destination",data.getDestination());
            intent.putExtra("description",data.getDescription());
            intent.putExtra("date_from",data.getDate_from());
            intent.putExtra("date_to",data.getDate_to());
            intent.putExtra("price",data.getPrice());

            mContext.startActivity(intent);



        }
    }));








}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelClassList.size();
}

public static class  MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView mactivity;
    TextView morigin;
    TextView mdestination;
    TextView mdescription;
    TextView mdate_from;
    TextView mdate_to;
    TextView mprice;
    ImageView img_activity;
    Button btnadd;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mactivity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvactivity);
        morigin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvorigin);
        mdestination = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdestination);
        mdescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdescription);
        mdate_from = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdate_from);
        mdate_to = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdate_to);
        mprice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
        img_activity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_activity);
        btnadd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnadd);












            }
}
```

}

---

CARTADAPTER

---

```
  public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<ModelClass2> modelClassList;

private Context mContext;

public CartAdapter(Context context, List<ModelClass2> modelClassList) {
    this.modelClassList = modelClassList;
    mContext = context;


}


@NonNull
@Override
public CartAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v); //ini
    // sialisasi ViewHolder


    return holder;


}

@NonNull
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

    final ModelClass2 data = modelClassList.get(i);

    myViewHolder.mactivity.getText();
    myViewHolder.morigin.setText(data.getOrigin());
    myViewHolder.mdestination.setText(data.getDestination());
    myViewHolder.mdescription.setText(data.getDescription());
    myViewHolder.mdate_from.setText(data.getDate_from());
    myViewHolder.mdate_to.setText(data.getDate_to());
    myViewHolder.mprice.setText(data.getPrice());







}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelClassList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView mactivity;
    TextView morigin;
    TextView mdestination;
    TextView mdescription;
    TextView mdate_from;
    TextView mdate_to;
    TextView mprice;
    ImageView img_activity;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mactivity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvactivity);
        morigin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvorigin);
        mdestination = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdestination);
        mdescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdescription);
        mdate_from = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdate_from);
        mdate_to = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdate_to);
        mprice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
        img_activity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_activity);



    }
}
```

}

---

CARTCLASS

---

```
  public class CART extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG ="GalleryActivity" ;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Button btnMainactivity;
Class ModelClass2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    btnMainactivity = findViewById(R.id.btnMainactivity);

    btnMainactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent abreCad = new Intent(CART.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(abreCad);




        }
    });


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<ModelClass2> modelClassList = new ArrayList<>();



   getIncomingIntent();


    CartAdapter adapter = new CartAdapter(CART.this, modelClassList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void getIncomingIntent(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingIntent: Checking for incoming intents");

    if(getIntent().hasExtra("activity")){
        Log.d(TAG, "getIncomingIntent: found intent extras");

        String activity = getIntent().getStringExtra("activity");

        setList(activity);


    }

}

private void setList(String activity){

    TextView mactivity = findViewById(R.id.tvactivity);
    mactivity.setText(activity);


}
```

}

---

**error part the last 3 lines in CartClass=**

---

>

```
TextView mactivity = findViewById(R.id.tvactivity);
        mactivity.setText(activity);
```

---

error

---

> 

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test, PID: 26271
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.CART.CART}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.test.CART.CART.setList(CART.java:84)
        at com.example.test.CART.CART.getIncomingIntent(CART.java:74)
        at com.example.test.CART.CART.onCreate(CART.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: where is `startActivity` ?

Comment: it start when i change activity because if i did start with the intent it will automatically change activites with the button pressed

Comment: when is "Change Activity" code ?

Comment: in the main activity with a different button i i will add it

Comment: are you get data from recyclerview which connected to data base ?

Comment: yes .. i receive the data and it appear perfectly with no errors

Comment: `activity_cart.xml` has id `tvactivity`?

Comment: nope , it has the recyclerView and in item_layout.xml has tvactivity

Comment: are you trying to setText to a textview in ViewHolder from Activity?

Comment: yes .. am i doing it wrong